# flexslider image size cover

Tags: html, css, flexslider

For my personal site http://stevengeorgeharris.com I have created a single page design with several divs stacked on top of each other. The divs are width: 100% and height: 100% so they scale with the browser, within each div I am using flexslider to create a fullscreen slideshow.

My problem is when the browser gets narrower the images within the flexslider container scale down leaving whitespace below.

This is the CSS for the flexslider image.

```
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; height:auto; display: block;}
```

Is there anyway to make the images act like this http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/css-1.php

Comment: I notice you have set a height of 100% to HTML. This doesn't work afaik. you'll have to set a fixed height. Percentage heights don't work at all unless at least one of the parents has a fixed height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you should use media query. You can read more about media query here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

I did what you wanted to do; with another picture and you can see the final result here: http://jsbin.com/olakit/2

Here is the code (the original picture is 1024 x 683 px ):

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height : 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 2000px) {
  img{
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Notice that the "min-width" should be more than the picture's width.